# Shrinkwrap remnants - during model wall creation

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am creating the wall of an object through shrinkwrapping a big sphere around the object, and then remeshing. Few cycles of this. However, I get some remnants of mesh between arch. How to solve that problem? Of course I can do it manually but it is a lot of work. After removing it there is a big hole in the mesh so again need to be corrected manually. Any simpler ideas?
[image: Image: Left the object. Right: after shrinkwraphig a sphere, however with mesh remnants between]

Comment: does it really have to be a sphere? Why not a tube?

Comment: Tube is working even worse. Its not covering the whole object, and produce same remnants.

Comment: Do you mean a cylinder fresh from the add menu or a topology of a few hundred verts that roughly follows your whatever that is with a subsurf to give it some verts?

Answer (score 3):

The Shrinkrap Modifier is not really a fire and forget kind of tool that takes care of everything. It needs some love.

Here is how I use it:

[image: All anime is naughty tentacles]

- I model a very low poly mesh that wraps around the target. In this case a simple circle with 6 verts. It's not just a blanket thrown over everything. Any topology worth considering is mirrored lowpoly in this mesh. The structure of this mesh is crucial. It makes sure my result has a nice flowing topology instead of being a random mess. Blender's workflow and chaotic topology don't harmonize all that well.
- Step two is a Subsurf, can be a simple one, so the Wrap has something to work with.
- Step three is the actual Shrinkwrap Modifier that gets its offet.
- Step four is adjusting the verts. In some places the modifier will goof up. It needs guidance. But since all the geometry is procedural, you can still adjust the lowpoly base to help the Shrinkwrap along. It'll search for the closest surface point and its the modeler's job to make sure the right spots are closest.

If you want to, you can sandwich the Shrinkwrap between two subsurfs where the first is for shrinking and the second is for smoothing.

Comment: Nice opening line.True for more than one tool.

Comment: @cegaton Blender never gets boring.